# Unit test on a method with a instantiated custom object

Tags: java, reflection, aem, junit5

How do I control the output value of the getCapturedCharacterResponse() for my junit 5 testing?

Example implementation:

```
class ToBeTestedClass{
  private CaptureResponseWrapper co;

  void triggeredMethod(HttpServletResponse s){
    co = new CaptureResponseWrapper(s);
    String s = co.getCapturedCharacterResponse();
  }
}

}
```

Currently junit 5 does not have support on powermock.

reference for https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/org/apache/sling/scripting/core/servlet/CaptureResponseWrapper.html

any suggestion or fix for this simple problem?

apologies noob here.

Comment: Did you fix this test case?

Comment: @ronnyfm Yes, it is fix, closing the question. thanks

Comment: No worries, you can answer your own question for people in the future facing the same issue :)